# How to copy Docker images from Docker to Nexus

Tags: docker, nexus

How can you copy all the latest repos from https://hub.docker.com/u/demisto and push them Nexus.

Security wants to have the docker images being uses in Nexus so they can be scanned or something like that.

Trying to avoid having to go repo by repo to get the latest image and then pulling them to my machine just to push it to Nexus. Not sure of what command to use or if there is tool to help automate copying these 200+ docker images.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `demisto-sdk` ? this sdk has command to download all your packs : `demisto-sdk download -o Packs/output_packs -a`